# Perform code with very low priority

Tags: ios, multithreading, performance, cocoa-touch, game-center

I know 2 ways to perform something in background.

1:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#>]
```

2:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  ...
});
```

Both methods don't help me. I'm reporting player's game score to Game Center and when I do It there is noticeable lag in gameplay on old devices like iPod 4G. But there is no real hurry. Is it possible to make this code perform with low CPU utilization? I do it after game over, but user can restart game immediately, and he will see little lags for about 2 seconds.

Score reporting code:

```
- (void) reportScore:(int64_t)score forLeaderboardID:(NSString*)category newBestTime:(BOOL)newBestTime {
    GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:category];
    scoreReporter.value = score;
    scoreReporter.context = 0;
    [scoreReporter reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
      //nothing here
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the low priority queue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
  ...
});
```

Comment: I can't really see any difference in performance with DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW and DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND

Comment: @user1561346 Well that will depend on load; if the device is not busy you won't notice any difference.

Comment: CPU and GPU utilization are lower than 50%. But I can see frame drops on score reporting.

Comment: @user1561346 When using the low priority queue?  How is the score reported?

Comment: @user1561346 Well the method `reportScoreWithCompletionHandler` implies that it runs asynchronously so it doesn't matter about the priority of the thread that call that code.  That's where you need to focus.

Comment: So there is no way to lower priority of this method?

Comment: @user1561346 No, not without changing its implementation.  You can call that code directly in the main thread given it works asychrnously anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just another suggestion, I'm not sure if it works or not:

```
-(void)lowPriorityThread {
    NSBlockOperation *b = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        //your code
    }];

    b.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriorityVeryLow;

    [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:b];
}
```